# MySQL select two columns multiple name value pair

Tags: mysql

I need help about generating query for multiple column.
part of my tbl_advert_specific_fields_values  table look like:

```
id advert_id   field_name      field_value
1  654         t1_sqft         50
2  655         t1_yearbuilt    1999
3  1521        t2_doorcount    5
4  656         t1_yearbuilt    2001
5  656         t1_sqft         29
6  654         t1_yearbuilt    2004


SELECT p.*, p.id AS id, p.title AS title, usr.id as advert_user_id,
            p.street_num, p.street,c.icon AS cat_icon,c.title AS cat_title,c.title AS cat_title,
            p.description as description,
            countries.title as country_name,
            states.title as state_name,
            date_FORMAT(p.created, '%Y-%m-%d') as fcreated 
            FROM tbl AS p
                LEFT JOIN tbl_advertmid AS pm ON pm.advert_id = p.id
                INNER JOIN tbl_usermid AS am ON am.advert_id = p.id
                LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS usr ON usr.id = am.user_id
                INNER JOIN tbl_categories AS c ON c.id = pm.cat_id 
                INNER JOIN tbl_advert_specific_fields_values AS asfv ON asfv.advert_id = p.id
                LEFT JOIN tbl_countries AS countries ON countries.id = p.country
                LEFT JOIN tbl_states AS states ON states.id = p.locstate
            WHERE p.published = 1 AND p.approved = 1 AND c.published = 1
                AND (asfv.field_name = 't1_yearbuilt' 
                AND CONVERT(asfv.field_value,SIGNED) <= 2004 )
                AND (asfv.field_name = 't1_sqft' 
                AND CONVERT(asfv.field_value,SIGNED) <= 50)
                AND p.price <= 10174945 AND (p.advert_type_id = 1) 
                AND (c.id = 43 OR c.parent = 43) 
    GROUP BY p.id 
        ORDER BY p.price DESC
```

ok, the problem is in this asfv query part that are generated dynamically. It belong to objects which represent adverts by its specific fields. asfv is actually advert_specific_fields_values table (table name say all about it).

Without part:

```
AND (asfv.field_name = 't1_yearbuilt'
AND CONVERT(asfv.field_value,SIGNED) <= 2004 )
AND (asfv.field_name = 't1_sqft' 
AND CONVERT(asfv.field_value,SIGNED) <= 50)
```

query return all adverts that belong on advert_type_id and price of them are less than 10.174.945,00 €.

All what I need is query update that return only adverts, for example t1_yearbuilt less than 2005 and t1_sqft less than 51 (advert_id => 654,656).

I also need query for values between for example t1_sqft  >=30 AND t1_sqft <=50 (advert_id => 654).

Can anybody know how, update this query?

TNX

Comment: If you actually have a question, please edit the posting and include it.

Comment: FWIW, the `GROUP BY p.id` as well as including `p.*` in the selected columns look nonsensical at first glance.

Comment: You are using LEFT JOINs in a few places where you then check the values in the WHERE clause. Unless checking for null this doesn't make sense. Use an INNER JOIN for tbl_advert_specific_fields_values, tbl_categories and tbl_advertmid. Also if a record on tbl can have multiple categories your GROUP BY will eliminate all but one of those categories (and which one it keeps will be undefined).